# Как понять этот кусок кода?

Tags: java

Добрый день.столкнулся в проекте с таким кодом

```
static {
    какой то код 
    ...
}
```

Что это за статик?это метод?тогда где его имя где его воид или ретурн.Прошу помочь с обьяснением

Comment: Это блок статической инициализации.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это статической блок инициализации (*class initializers*). Код, находящийся в этом блоке, будет выполнен единожды (при загрузке класса `ClassLoader`-ом).

В статическом блоке, можно, например, инициализировать статические переменные, либо загружать библиотеки (`System.loadLibrary("libName")`).

Также, в классе могут быть нестатические блоки (*instance initializers*). Они выполняются при создании объекта класса (вне зависимости от того, какой конструктор будет вызван).